# How can I improve showing several different measures for one sample?

Tags: tables, siunitx

I am displaying 4 bits of data (three of them are of the same type) for a sample shown on the left of it. Is there a way I could improve this?

So far I came up with this layout:

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
tikz,
siunitx,
xspace
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}



\begin{document}
\begin{center}\small
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\begin{minipage}{2.1cm}
\tikz \filldraw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{tabular}{r@{\hspace{3pt}}S}
\( a = \) & \SI{1.11}{\metre} \\
\( b = \) & \SI{2.22}{\newton}  \\
\( c = \) & \SI{3.33}{\newton} \\
\( d = \) & \SI{5.13}{\newton}  
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{minipage}{2.1cm}
\tikz \filldraw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{tabular}{r@{\hspace{3pt}}S}
\( a = \) & \SI{1.11}{\metre} \\
\( b = \) & \SI{2.22}{\newton}  \\
\( c = \) & \SI{3.33}{\newton} \\
\( d = \) & \SI{5.13}{\newton}  
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your `S` columns here are not doing anything as the material is escaped from alignment. Perhaps you just want an `l` column, or if you want numerical alignment you perhaps want two columns (one for the number, one for the unit).

Comment: You could just use a    \parbox and halign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data should be split in three columns; for the general layout I show two ways.

Note the format of the data subtables:

```
\begin{tabular}{
  >{$}r<{{}$}
  @{}
  S[table-format=1.2]
  @{\,}
  s
}
```

1. The first column is right aligned in math mode; the `{}` ensures good spacing after the `=` sign.
2. The second column is `S`; adjust the `table-format` to the actual format.
3. The third column is `s`, for specifying the unit without using `\si` in each cell. (Thanks to Harish for recalling this option.)

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo just for the example
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\omitvalue}{\multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{---}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering\small

\hfill
\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=2cm,valign=c]{A}\quad
\begin{tabular}{
  >{$}r<{{}$}
  @{}
  S[table-format=1.2]
  @{\,}
  s
}
a = & 1.11 & \metre  \\
b = & 2.22 & \newton \\
c = & 3.33 & \newton \\
d = & 5.13 & \newton  
\end{tabular}
\hfill\hfill
\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=2cm,valign=c]{A}\quad
\begin{tabular}{
  >{$}r<{{}$}
  @{}
  S[table-format=1.2]
  @{\,}
  s
}
a = & 1.11 & \metre  \\
b = & 2.22 & \newton \\
c = & 3.33 & \newton \\
d = & \omitvalue
\end{tabular}\hspace*{\fill}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering\small

\begin{tabular}{c@{\ }l@{\qquad}c@{\ }l}
  \includegraphics[height=2cm,width=2cm,valign=c]{A} &
  \begin{tabular}{
    >{$}r<{{}$}
    @{}
    S[table-format=1.2]
    @{\,}
    s
  }
  a = & 1.11 & \metre  \\
  b = & 2.22 & \newton \\
  c = & 3.33 & \newton \\
  d = & 5.13 & \newton  
  \end{tabular}
&
  \includegraphics[height=2cm,width=2cm,valign=c]{A} &
  \begin{tabular}{
    >{$}r<{{}$}
    @{}
    S[table-format=1.2]
    @{\,}
    s
  }
  a = & 1.11 & \metre  \\
  b = & 2.22 & \newton \\
  c = & 3.33 & \newton \\
  d = & \omitvalue
  \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @HarishKumar Right!

Comment: Hm... to be honest, that looks quite "odd".

Comment: @henry What's odd?

Comment: Well, I got the exact same output from your code, so the little samples aren't aligned anymore. Portraying the whole batch like this does not look appropriate. I mean I imagined a lot of tips, but not putting the (fake) pictures like this. Did I miss something?

Comment: @henry They are two distinct examples in two distinct tables; I just showed two alternative methods for laying out the tables: the first just uses normal spacings, the second uses a big tabular.

Comment: Oh... woops. :)